# Как экранировать html-теги и php?

Tags: php, экранирование

Добрый день. Есть ли какой нибудь способ экранировать все html теги кроме некоторых? Допустим оставить только <p>, <b> а остальное экранировать? И как можно экранировать <? php ?> ? По идее я знаю как это сделать, но получается что убирается только тег, а контент внутри него остается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используй функцию strip_tags. 
Так же он уберет тебе php даже не будет показывать символы HTML.

```
$text = strip_tags ($text, '<p>');
$text = strip_tags ($text, '<b>');
```

Comment: Да, проблему тегов это решает (и php наверно тоже) :). Проблему с ?php можно так же решить через htmlspecialchars

Answer (score 3):

по поводу p и b - один из способов, через замену, заменим <p> на {p} экранизируем, а потом обратно подставим. ЛИБО - экранизация, это замена символа < на его код - &lt; значит можно сделать так:

```
$text = htmlspecialchars($text);
$text = str_replace("&lt;p&gt;", "<p>", $text);
$text = str_replace("&lt;/p&gt;", "</p>", $text);
```

Comment: тоже как вариант, но лучше strip_tags.

Answer (score 1):

Если правильно понял, то так

```
<?php
$text = preg_replace("~\<p(.*?)\>(.*?)\</p\>~msi", "{p\\1}\\2{/p}", $text);
$text = preg_replace("~\<b(.*?)\>(.*?)\</b\>~msi", "{b\\1}\\2{/b}", $text);

$text = htmlspecialchars($text);

$text = preg_replace("~\{p(.*?)\}(.*?)\{/p\}~msi", "<p\\1>\\2</p>", $text);
$text = preg_replace("~\{b(.*?)\}(.*?)\{/b\}~msi", "<b\\1>\\2</b>", $text);
?>
```

Если не совсем правильно понял если нудно просто почистить весь текст он лишних html тегов то так

```
<?php
    $text = strip_tags($text, "<p><b>");
?>
```

Экранировать PHP код можно скорее всего таким образом

```
<?php
$code = <<<PHP
<?php
    phpinfo();
?>
PHP;
$code = htmlspecialchars($code);
?>
```